# How to get linkedin connections?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api, social-networking

In my app user has a option to login to app through linkedin.after login i have to get user's connections. when i try to get users connections i am getting response as

```
{
   "errorCode": 0,
   "message": "Access to connections denied",
   "requestId": "60A0DS1MZE",
   "status": 403,
   "timestamp": 1386682428799
 }
```

Here is my code

```
 -(void)GetConnectionsCall
 {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections"];

   OAMutableURLRequest *request =
   [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                   consumer:_oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                      token:_oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                   callback:nil
                          signatureProvider:nil];
   [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];



   OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
   [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                        delegate:self
               didFinishSelector:@selector(connectionsApiCallResult:didFinish:)
                 didFailSelector:@selector(connectionsApiCallResult:didFail:)];
 }


- (void)connectionsApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinish:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"connectionsApiCallResult====%@",responseBody);

}

- (void)connectionsApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFail:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using OAuth Starter Kit try this . . . .

1. first go to https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer edit your App scope , make sure you have checked the r_network scope .
2. then go to OAuthLoginView of you project , then go to -(void) requestTokenFromProvider method .

edit you scope in below lines .

```
OARequestParameter *nameParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"scope"
value:@"r_fullprofile+rw_nus+r_network"];

OARequestParameter * scopeParameter=[OARequestParameter requestParameter:@"scope" 
value:@"r_fullprofile rw_nus r_network"];
```

Comment: k let me check this again

Comment: and I am getting oauth verifer as null here is  oauth_token  result       ==="f824e868-2139-4bdb-b9ff-b0cf852aff69" oauth_token_secret "167c0202-a9c7-46e6-bbe7-32c3e9a9c16a" oauth_verifier "(null)"

Comment: Still in method - (void)requestTokenResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinish:(NSData *)data; i am getting ticket.didSucceed= NO any help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for permissions.. When this is not done you are not allowed to query this information.

Everything documented here: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api

Comment: Do we need to call any other services for permissions

Comment: Just read the usage part of the website and read this chapter of permissions http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting . Afterwards you know what you need to do